# If $x≤^∗y$ has the $\text{BP}$(in $X^2$) we can say that A is meager?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space. Let $(I,<)$ be a wellordered set and $(A_i)_{i∈I}$ a family of sets meager in $X$. Let $A=⋃_{i∈I}A_i$. If consider the relation $x≤^∗y$ defined by:

$x,y∈A$ $\wedge$ (the <- least $i$ with $x∈A_i$) $≤$ (the <-least $j$ with $y∈A_j$).

If $x≤^∗y$ has the $\text{BP}$(in $X^2$) we can say that A is meager?. Were $\text{BP}$ say Baire property.

Any suggestion to solve this question,thank you very much.

But we have to :

If $X$ be nonempty, perfect Polish space, with < be wellordering of $X$. Then $<⊆X^2$ does not have the $\text{BP}$.